# No recent questions with "need answers" and "favorite tags"

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I'm using the following URL to access SO, with the new nav enabled:

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&tagFilter=favorite

I have 12 favorite tags:

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [common-lisp](/questions/tagged/common-lisp) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) [php](/questions/tagged/php) [python](/questions/tagged/python) [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

So the above URL redirects to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=all&sort=newest&tags=bash%20c%20c%2b%2b%20common-lisp%20javascript%20jquery%20linux%20lisp%20mysql%20php%20python%20regex&mode=any

Until today, there would always be some new questions to answer. But now, the most recent question is dated yesterday, and the next ones are from July 10, July 9, June 25, June 25, and June 19.

Comment: We're looking at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to included bountied questions in the "all" show, I had inadvertently reverted the need answer behavior to the old, much less useful behavior of the "unanswered" top level section.

I've rewritten the tag engine search so it works as expected.

Comment: I noticed another side effect of this fix. SO is now displaying "N questions with new activity" like other SE sites. I thought this was supposed to be disabled in SO because it's so busy.