# Confusion about need answers > no answer > sorting options at Meta.SE new navigation

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

I am totally confused by the sorting options/choices given for the "**no answer**" show filter under the "**need answers**" tab. To understand/explain it better, I would like to share the following screenshots:

Here my home tab is set to "**need answers**":

> [image]

Show filter menu gives you 3 options i.e. "all", "no answer" and "bounties". I'm currently on "**all**" option (highlighted in gray color bkg.)

> [image]

The "all" filter gives 3 sorting options i.e. "newest", "votes" and "recently active". They all make sense here. Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

Now I selected "no answer" option from the show filter menu which changes the sorting options by giving two more options to choose from. So, here we have now "newest", "votes", "ending", "recently active" and "bounty size". But, I don't understand why we have given the "ending" and "bounty size" (marked with red ? mark) sorting options for "no answer" filter. They don't make sense at all. Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

Then I moved on to the last option i.e. "bounties" of the show filter menu which gives me the *exact same* 5 sorting options given to me for the "no answer" filter. But, here they *all* (especially the "ending" and "bounty size") make sense. Also, I can see the results shown based on these sorting options. Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

So, my confusion is about the two sorting options i.e. "ending" and "bounty size" given for the "**no answer**" option of the show filter. They really don't make sense at all. Also, I could not understand the results shown after applying these two options on the "no answer" option.

I *guess* they were supposed to be *removed* from the sorting options filter menu upon the selection of "no answer" show filter. That's what I can conclude here. But, I could be wrong here. Can anyone please explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here:

1. that tab has [some problems which we are sorting out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261352/no-recent-questions-with-need-answers-and-favorite-tags) (it's only showing stuff without answers and with the wrong order).
2. sorting by bounty size or bounty ending makes sense in the no answer show: it shows questions with bounties and no answers.

---

Update:

1. Issues are now solved
2. Those labels only appear with bounties now, hopefully this clears matters.

Comment: Thanks for the hotfix!! I love it and played with all options. Works like a charm!!